# Problems merging data in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am trying to merge different modules from a survey. Some modules differ in the number of observations. For example, expenditure is reported at the household level, whereas income is reported at the individual level.

Consider the aforementioned case. Expenditure module contains a householdID only, but income module a householdID and a personID, so I am merging them at the householdID and I set that ID to be the index in each module.

To merge these to modules, I try:

```py
Merged = pandas.merge(expenditure, income, how = 'outer', left_index = True, right_index = True)
```

Instead of having a merge I have IDs replicated with blocks of NaN, so it is not merging by the index but appends each module.

I hope somebody can help

Comment: I meant Merged = pandas.merge(expenditure, income, how = 'outer', left_index = True, right_index = True)

Comment: Outer merge will return any rows that do not have the same key-pair value. Are you sure that is the join you want to use?

Comment: Perhaps what you mean is a `how='left', on='householdID'` ?

Comment: Did you try? Merged = pandas.merge(expenditure, income, how = 'outer')